# How to get all toggle values from form submission in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi select field which toggles more field when selected multiple options. For example

```
<label for="projectType">Project Type<span class="icon-required">Required</span></label>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
          <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
          <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
          <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
          <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
            </select>

#if($existelem1.Type1)
    <fieldset class="group elem1" style="display:none;">
        <legend><span>Type1</span></legend>
        #foreach($elem1coll in $elem1collOptions)
            <span class="radio">
                    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="Type1" id="elem1coll_${elem1coll}" value="$elem1coll"#if("${Type1}" == $elem1coll) checked="checked" #end>
                    <label for="elem1coll_${elem1coll}">$elem1coll</label>
                </span>
        #end
    </fieldset>
#end
#if($existelem1.Type2)
    <fieldset class="group elem1" style="display:none;">
        <legend><span>Type2</span></legend>
                <span class="radio">
                    #foreach($elem1Po in $elem1PoOptions)
                        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="Type2" id="elem1Po_${elem1Po}" value="$elem1Po"#if("${Type2}" == $elem1Po) checked="checked" #end>
                    <label for="elem1Po_${elem1Po}">$elem1Po</label>
                    #end
                </span>
    </fieldset>
#end
```

For example If I select "elem 1" and "elem 2" it toggles two checkboxes each.But when I check values using:

```
var params = compress(jQuery("#createMyForm").serialize());

console.log(params)
prints projectType=elem1,elem2&elem1.Type1=Yes&elem1.Type2=Yes&elem2.Type1=&elem2.Type1=&
```

It only sends the values of "elem 1" checkboxes and skips the "elem 2" checkboxes. How can i fix this.

Comment: what is `compress`?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle ?

Comment: @shennan Compress is a function just to append all input as a string. Not at all important here as far as this question is concerned.

Comment: @Loading.. Creating a jsfiddle would be really difficult in this case as I am using velcoity as template

Comment: how does elem1,elem2 relate to that `<select>` tag? you have an name of my-select[], and values of elem_1, elem_2, elem_3 and elem_4 ... where is elem1 and elem2 coming from?

Comment: `Compress is a function just to append all input as a string. Not at all important here as far as this question is concerned` so what is the output of `jQuery("#createMyForm").serialize()`

Comment: It seems that you didn't getting all the selected values from dropdown when you submit the form ?

Comment: the code you posted (as opposed to whatever velcoity template is, and whatever the heck compress ACTUALLY does) works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/vqhgrxzy/

Comment: @JaromandaX Your jsfiddle donot toggles anycheckbox options to select. My multiselect is working fine.

Comment: Can you try with name="my-select" instead of name="my-select[]" ? if not then try to get the all selected values from dropdown.

Comment: @Loading.. yeah that's true, but why it is happening as the checkboxes are in the scope of form

Comment: `donot toggles anycheckbox options` - my code is your code that you posted ... not sure how your code would have checkboxes, - we can only answer **the code that is posted** - not something that you haven't posted

Comment: I'm guessing that this `velcoity template` drastically changes the actual DOM that is presented on the page, judging from the names in the console log that have only a passing resemblance to the names in the code you actually posted

Comment: Added the code for elem 1 checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not getting all the selected options from the multiple dropdown.

I would recommend to use.

```
var values = [];
var keys = [];

$('#my-select :selected').each(function(i, selectedElement) {
   values[i] = $(selectedElement).val();
   keys[i] = $(selectedElement).text();
});
```

Comment: that's what jquery.serialize does